# Out of memory in LineReader

Tags: c#, stringreader

I am making a program that reads a `.tyd` file and tries to translate all the text between the " from English to Italian.

GoToDesk **translate->** "Looking for computer"

The problem is that I am still getting "Out of memory".

The code is:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Net;
using MiscUtil.IO;

namespace Soft_inc
{
 class MyProject
{
    public static string TranslateText(string input, string languagePair)
    {
        string url = String.Format("http://translate.google.it/?hl=en&ie=UTF8&text={0}&langpair={1}", input, languagePair);
        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        webClient.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
        string result = webClient.DownloadString(url);
        result = result.Substring(result.IndexOf("<span title=\"") + "<span title=\"".Length);
        result = result.Substring(result.IndexOf(">") + 1);
        result = result.Substring(0, result.IndexOf("</span>"));
        return result.Trim();
}
       public static void Main()
    {
        string path_file = @"H:\Games\Software.In.v11.7.62\Software.In.v11.7.62\Localization\Italiano\idk\UI.tyd";

        string Ftext = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(path_file);
        ArrayList ar = new ArrayList();
    Console.WriteLine("This may require some time.");
    foreach (string line in new LineReader(() => new StringReader(Ftext)))
    {
        if(line.IndexOf("\"") == -1) continue;
        string text = line.Substring(line.IndexOf("\""));
        text = text.Replace("\"","");

        if(text.Length == 0) continue;
        ar.Add(text);
    }

    int idk = 0;

    while(true)
    {
        idk++;
        if(idk == ar.Count) break;
        string oldT = (string)ar[idk];
        Ftext = Ftext.Replace(oldT, TranslateText(oldT,"en|it"));
    }


    System.IO.File.WriteAllText("UI.tyd",Ftext);
}
}


}
```

Maybe it is because the file has 2535 lines of text?
How I can fix this?

Comment: What is `LineReader`? It isn't part of the BCL as far as I know. The number of lines also isn't that interesting without the length of the lines. How large is the whole file? You should include an example of the file structure of the .tyd file (but since this seems to be a from a third party which probably haven't given you permission to publish it you should not include any real data)

Comment: *Maybe it is because the file has 2535 lines of text?* - depends how long the lines are but I highly doubt it

Comment: General note: Having one loop operate on each line of FText and one loop the operate overall all of FText (for a value relating to each line) seems “suspicious”.

Comment: Anyway, if we’re debugging this, as opposed to rewriting it initially as a streaming approach, I would 1) check the size of tyd file to ensure the total size easily fits in memory and; 2) attach a debugger and watch the process memory change over the execution of each loop (there are two loops).

Comment: I *suspect* the issue might come from the second loop and an expanding cyclic replacement. The translated replacement value can be observed during #2 above.

Comment: While updating the code rest of the code, it might also be prudent to switch to HttpClient and a single instance for the entire unit-of-work (ie. create it once for every call in the loop).

Comment: `WebClient webClient = new WebClient();` looks pretty bad also, you're going to run out of ports. Instead cache the client

Comment: some advice: don't use ArrayList unless you are stuck in .NET 1.x

Comment: Thank you for those suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [StreamReader](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader?view=net-5.0) class. It is not necessary to read all file content into RAM. Open one StreamReader and one [StreamWriter](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter?view=net-5.0). Reed file line by line and write translated data into a temporary file. When all content is translated just [move](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.io.file.move?view=net-5.0) temp file to needed destination. Don't forget to close source and destination handles before moving.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Seems that is working. Thank you!